# Enable Follow mode for helm-org-in-buffer-headings

Tags: helm, helm-sources

I want to enable `helm-follow-mode` for `helm-org-in-buffer-headings`. This is what I have so far:

```
(add-hook 'helm-after-initialize-hook 
            ((lambda () (helm-attrset 
                         'follow 1 helm-org-in-buffer-headings))))
```

But not working yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a few clues [here](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/FAQ#why-is-a-customizable-helm-source-nil) and this is what worked for me:

```
(with-eval-after-load "helm-org"
  (cl-defmethod helm-setup-user-source ((source helm-org-headings-class))
    (set-slot-value source 'follow 1)))
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks @jagrg!