# helm narrow to subtree

Tags: org-mode, helm-sources

I am using `helm-org-in-buffer-headings` to search headings in the current buffer. I am using this script (provided by jagra [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47827/enable-follow-mode-for-helm-org-in-buffer-headings)) to activate follow mode:

```
  (with-eval-after-load "helm-org"
    (cl-defmethod helm-setup-user-source ((source helm-org-headings-class))
      (set-slot-value source 'follow 1)))
```

So as I navigate through the helm source list, I see the corresponding headings in the main buffer. For example:

[image]

Instead of seeing the entire document, while I browse through the source list, I would like to narrow-to-subtree.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could change `helm-org-goto-marker` to start with `widen` and end with `org-narrow-to-subtree`, but that would keep the buffer narrowed when you press RET or exit the minibuffer.

Comment: Hi @jagrg That could work. How would you implement it? Can you post a code snippet? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `helm-org-goto-marker` to start with `widen` and end with `org-narrow-to-subtree`, but that would keep the buffer narrowed when you press RET or exit the minibuffer.

```el
(advice-add 'helm-org-goto-marker :before (lambda (_marker) (widen)))
(advice-add 'helm-org-goto-marker :after (lambda (_marker) (org-narrow-to-subtree)))
```

For a similar effect that does not require narrowing, I would suggest moving the headline to the top of the screen. You may want to show the subheadings as well:

```el
(advice-add 'helm-org-goto-marker :after (lambda (_marker)
                                           (recenter-top-bottom 0)
                                           (outline-show-children)))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @jagrg!